# Finding the maximum volume of a cylinder.

Tags: derivatives

The cylinder is open topped and is made from $200~\text{cm}^2$ of material.

So what I have done is said $S = 2\pi r^2h +2\pi r^2$.
\begin{align}
2\pi r^2h +2\pi r^2 & = 200\\
2\pi r^2h & = 200 - 2\pi r^2\\
h & = \frac{200 - 2\pi r^2}{2\pi r^2}
\end{align}
Subbing this into the volume equation I get

$$V = (\pi r^2)\frac{200-2\pi r^2}{2\pi r^2}$$

Having trouble differentiating that equation.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Please check the formula for $S$. It is wrong

Comment: Notice that your formula for $S$ assumes that the cylinder is closed at the top.

Comment: Thanks, Ill take a look at that and revise my equations so far.  I will check the tutorial and make sure the revised equations are properly displayed

Answer (score 0):

Your equation for S is wrong. The lateral area is $2\pi rh$ and the base area $\pi r^2$, so S equals $2\pi rh+\pi r^2$.

Following your steps, I get $$V = (\pi r^2)\frac{200-\pi r^2}{2\pi r} = 100r-\frac{\pi}{2}r^3$$
Deriving a polynomial works like [this](https://www.freemathhelp.com/derivative-of-polynomial.html). Summarized: $\frac{d}{dx} x^n = nx^{n-1}$

This means $$\frac{d}{dr}V = 100-\frac{3\pi}{2}r^2$$
I hope you can take it from there.